# Words with two or more capital letters in Java

Tags: java, regex

Words with at least 2 Capital letters and with any special letters (like @#$%^&*()_-+= and so on...) optional.

I tried:

```
 public static boolean isWordHas2Caps(String s) {
        return s.matches("\\b(?:\\p{Ll}*\\p{Lu}){2,}\\p{Ll}*\\b");
    }
```

But, I am getting

```
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("eHJHJK"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("YUIYUI"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("LkfjkdJkdfj"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("LLdkjkd"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("OhdfjhdsjO"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("LLLuoiu9898"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("Ohdf&jh/dsjO"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("auuuu"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("JJJJJJJJ"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("YYYY99999"));
    System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("ooooPPPP"));
```

Output:

```
true   eHJHJK
true   YUIYUI
true   LkfjkdJkdfj
true   LLdkjkd
true   OhdfjhdsjO
false   LLLuoiu9898       It should be true but getting false
false   Ohdf&jh/dsjO      It should be true but getting false
false   auuuu
true   JJJJJJJJ
false   YYYY99999        It should be true but getting false
true   ooooPPPP
```

I think, I should in the regexp and numbers and Special letters. How can I do that?

Comment: can you correct my regexp and share correct regexp please.

Comment: Use `Pattern.compile("\\p{Lu}\\P{Lu}*\\p{Lu}").matcher(s).find()`, the backtracking is lightweight with this expression as `\p{Lu}` and `\P{Lu}` are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Sun, did any of the answers below help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You want to check if there are at least two uppercase letters anywhere in a string that can contain arbitrary chars.

Then, you can use

```java
public static boolean isWordHas2Caps(String s) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\p{Lu}\\P{Lu}*\\p{Lu}").matcher(s).find();
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/jww6fV).

Alternatively, if you still want to use `String#matches` you can use the following (keeping in mind that we need to match the entire string):

```java
public static boolean isWordHas2Caps(String s) {
    return s.matches("(?s)(?:\\P{Lu}*\\p{Lu}){2}.*");
}
```

The `(?s)(?:\\P{Lu}*\\p{Lu}){2}.*` regex matches

- `(?s)` - the `Pattern.DOTALL` embedded flag option (makes `.` match any chars)
- `(?:\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}){2}` - two occurrences of any zero or more chars other than uppercase letters and then an uppercase letter
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Your code did not return expected results because all of them contain non-letter characters, while `String#matches()` requires a full string match against a pattern, and yours matches strings that contains letters only.

That is why you should

- Make sure you can match anywhere inside a string, and `Matcher.find` does this job best
- `\p{Lu}\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}` pattern will find any sequence of an uppercase letter + any zero or more non-letters + an uppercase letter
- Alternatively, you can use `(?s)(?:\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}){2}.*` regex to match a full string that contains at least two uppercase letters.

Comment: FYI, see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2nFSx/1), just had to subtract a newline from `\P{L}`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update:

A valuable comment from [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava):

> Probably `s.matches("(?:\\S*\\p{Lu}){2}\\S*");`  may be better

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tpcLib/1) of the above solution.

#### Original answer:

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tLp0kU/1), `\b.*\p{Lu}.*\p{Lu}.*\b` as shown below:

```
public static boolean isWordHas2Caps(String s) {
    return s.matches("\\b.*\\p{Lu}.*\\p{Lu}.*\\b");
}
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("eHJHJK"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("YUIYUI"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("LkfjkdJkdfj"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("LLdkjkd"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("OhdfjhdsjO"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("LLLuoiu9898"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("Ohdf&jh/dsjO"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("auuuu"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("JJJJJJJJ"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("YYYY99999"));
        System.out.println(isWordHas2Caps("ooooPPPP"));
    }

    public static boolean isWordHas2Caps(String s) {
        return s.matches("\\b.*\\p{Lu}.*\\p{Lu}.*\\b");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
false
true
true
true
```

Comment: Probably `s.matches("(?:\\S*\\p{Lu}){2}\\S*");` may be better